# exec-maven-plugin with 2 executions does not work

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have the maven code below under the build:plugins tag. It is supposed to run two different executions of the avro tools. One to create the schema and another to generate java source. It does not matter what I do it only executes one time. I tried to create two entries for the exec-maven-plugin but it always skips one.
The only way to work is to execute first these two commands:
mvn exec:java@avro
mvn exec:java@java
But this will require to change the CD/CI pipeline and I would just rather have it to work with a simple
mvn install

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>avsc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>org.apache.avro.tool.Main</mainClass>
                        <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                        <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                        <executableDependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                            <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
                        </executableDependency>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>idl2schemata</argument>
                            <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/avdl/Event.avdl</argument>
                            <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>org.apache.avro.tool.Main</mainClass>
                        <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                        <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                        <executableDependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                            <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
                        </executableDependency>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>compile</argument>
                            <argument>-string</argument>
                            <argument>-bigDecimal</argument>
                            <argument>schema</argument>
                            <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/Event.avsc</argument>
                            <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${avro.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

#

output from maven -e -X generate-sources

#

```
[DEBUG] Project:       io.digital.prj1:prj1-testing:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [test]
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <directory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <excludeDefaultDirectories default-value="false">${clean.excludeDefaultDirectories}</excludeDefaultDirectories>
  <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.clean.failOnError}</failOnError>
  <followSymLinks default-value="false">${clean.followSymLinks}</followSymLinks>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <reportDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <retryOnError default-value="true">${maven.clean.retryOnError}</retryOnError>
  <skip default-value="false">${clean.skip}</skip>
  <testOutputDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
  <verbose>${clean.verbose}</verbose>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (avsc)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <arguments>
    <argument>idl2schemata</argument>
    <argument>I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing/src/main/avdl/DDAMemotestingEvent.avdl</argument>
    <argument>I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing/src/main/avro</argument>${exec.arguments}</arguments>
  <classpathScope default-value="runtime">compile</classpathScope>
  <cleanupDaemonThreads default-value="true">false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
  <commandlineArgs>${exec.args}</commandlineArgs>
  <daemonThreadJoinTimeout default-value="15000">${exec.daemonThreadJoinTimeout}</daemonThreadJoinTimeout>
  <executableDependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
  </executableDependency>
  <includePluginDependencies default-value="false">true</includePluginDependencies>
  <includeProjectDependencies default-value="true">${exec.includeProjectDependencies}</includeProjectDependencies>
  <keepAlive default-value="false">${exec.keepAlive}</keepAlive>
  <killAfter default-value="-1">${exec.killAfter}</killAfter>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <mainClass>org.apache.avro.tool.Main</mainClass>
  <pluginDependencies default-value="${plugin.artifacts}"/>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <remoteRepositories default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${exec.skip}</skip>
  <sourceRoot>${sourceRoot}</sourceRoot>
  <stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads default-value="false">${exec.stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads}</stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads>
  <testSourceRoot>${testSourceRoot}</testSourceRoot>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (java)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <arguments>
    <argument>compile</argument>
    <argument>-string</argument>
    <argument>-bigDecimal</argument>
    <argument>schema</argument>
    <argument>I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing/src/main/avro/DDAMemotestingEvent.avsc</argument>
    <argument>I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing/src/main/java</argument>${exec.arguments}</arguments>
  <classpathScope default-value="runtime">compile</classpathScope>
  <cleanupDaemonThreads default-value="true">false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
  <commandlineArgs>${exec.args}</commandlineArgs>
  <daemonThreadJoinTimeout default-value="15000">${exec.daemonThreadJoinTimeout}</daemonThreadJoinTimeout>
  <executableDependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
  </executableDependency>
  <includePluginDependencies default-value="false">true</includePluginDependencies>
  <includeProjectDependencies default-value="true">${exec.includeProjectDependencies}</includeProjectDependencies>
  <keepAlive default-value="false">${exec.keepAlive}</keepAlive>
  <killAfter default-value="-1">${exec.killAfter}</killAfter>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <mainClass>org.apache.avro.tool.Main</mainClass>
  <pluginDependencies default-value="${plugin.artifacts}"/>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <remoteRepositories default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${exec.skip}</skip>
  <sourceRoot>${sourceRoot}</sourceRoot>
  <stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads default-value="false">${exec.stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads}</stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads>
  <testSourceRoot>${testSourceRoot}</testSourceRoot>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=627, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=175, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=31, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=349, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=8830, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=46}
[DEBUG] io.digital.prj1:prj1-testing:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]       org.scala-sbt:test-interface:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ prj1-testing ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=4, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=4, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=4, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=187, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=0}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.6.1:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.7:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:runtime
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.6.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) directory = I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing\target
[DEBUG]   (f) excludeDefaultDirectories = false
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) followSymLinks = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) reportDirectory = I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) retryOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) testOutputDirectory = I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing\target\test-classes
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Deleting I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing\target

[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (avsc) @ prj1-testing ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=206, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=64, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=148, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=343, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=0}
[DEBUG] org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.0:
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) arguments = [idl2schemata, I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing/src/main/avdl/DDAMemotestingEvent.avdl, I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing/src/main/avro]
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathScope = compile
[DEBUG]   (f) cleanupDaemonThreads = false
[DEBUG]   (f) daemonThreadJoinTimeout = 15000
[DEBUG]   (s) groupId = org.apache.avro
[DEBUG]   (s) artifactId = avro-tools
[DEBUG]   (f) executableDependency = org.apache.avro:avro-tools
[DEBUG]   (f) includePluginDependencies = true
[DEBUG]   (f) includeProjectDependencies = true
[DEBUG]   (f) keepAlive = false
[DEBUG]   (f) killAfter = -1
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/USER2/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) mainClass = org.apache.avro.tool.Main
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginDependencies = [org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.5.0:, org.apache.avro:avro-tools:jar:1.8.2:runtime, org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:runtime, org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:runtime, com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.7:runtime, org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.1.3:runtime, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.8.1:runtime, org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:runtime, org.apache.avro:avro-compiler:jar:1.8.2:runtime, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:runtime, org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:runtime, commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:runtime, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.7:runtime, org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.8.2:runtime, org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:runtime, org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:runtime, io.netty:netty:jar:3.5.13.Final:runtime, org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:runtime, org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:1.8.2:runtime, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:runtime, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:runtime, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:runtime, org.apache.avro:trevni-core:jar:1.8.2:runtime, org.apache.avro:trevni-avro:jar:1.8.2:runtime, org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:hadoop2:1.8.2:runtime, org.apache.avro:trevni-core:jar:tests:1.8.2:runtime, org.apache.avro:trevni-avro:jar:tests:1.8.2:runtime, org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:runtime, net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:4.7:runtime, com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:runtime, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:runtime, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:compile, org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile]
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: io.digital.prj1:prj1-testing:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [      id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
    proxy: approxy.jpmchase.net:8080
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Invoking : org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(idl2schemata, I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing/src/main/avdl/DDAMemotestingEvent.avdl, I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing/src/main/avro)
[DEBUG] Selected plugin Dependencies will be included.
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: avro to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: jackson-core-asl to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: jackson-mapper-asl to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: paranamer to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: snappy-java to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: jopt-simple to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: findbugs-annotations to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: junit to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: hamcrest-core to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: slf4j-simple to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding plugin dependency artifact: avro-tools to classpath
[DEBUG] Project Dependencies will be included.
[DEBUG] Collected project artifacts [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile, ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile, ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile, org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile, org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile, org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile, org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile, org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile, org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile, org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile, javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile, org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile, com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile, org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile, io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client:jar:1.5.0.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:1.1.9.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.1.9.RELEASE:compile, io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-cloudfoundry-connector:jar:1.5.0.RELEASE:compile, io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-connector-core:jar:1.5.0.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-core:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile, io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-spring-connector:jar:1.5.0.RELEASE:compile, org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.18:compile, org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile, io.pivotal.spring.cloud:cloudfoundry-certificate-truster:jar:1.0.1.RELEASE:compile, junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile, org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:1.1.7.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile, org.apache.avro:avro-tools:jar:1.8.2:provided, org.apache.avro:avro-compiler:jar:1.8.2:provided, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:provided, org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:provided, commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:provided, org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.8.2:provided, org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:provided, org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:provided, io.netty:netty:jar:3.5.13.Final:provided, org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:provided, org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:1.8.2:provided, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile, org.apache.avro:trevni-core:jar:1.8.2:provided, org.apache.avro:trevni-avro:jar:1.8.2:provided, org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:hadoop2:1.8.2:provided, org.apache.avro:trevni-core:jar:tests:1.8.2:provided, org.apache.avro:trevni-avro:jar:tests:1.8.2:provided, org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile, net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:4.7:provided, com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:provided, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile, org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.0:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile, org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile, nekohtml:xercesMinimal:jar:1.9.6.2:compile, nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.6.2:compile, org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile, org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh-common:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile, com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.38:compile, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:compile, org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile, org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile, org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile, com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.7:compile, org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.1.3:compile, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.8.1:compile, org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:compile, org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:0.10.0.0:compile, net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.3.0:compile, org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.8:compile, org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:jar:3.0.5:compile, org.scalactic:scalactic_2.11:jar:3.0.5:compile, org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.12:compile, org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:jar:1.0.6:compile, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0:compile, org.scalacheck:scalacheck_2.11:jar:1.13.5:compile, org.scala-sbt:test-interface:jar:1.0:compile]
[DEBUG] Collected project classpath [I:\dev\examples\prj1-cass-testing\target\classes]
[DEBUG] Adding to classpath : file:/I:/dev/examples/prj1-cass-testing/target/classes
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: spring-boot-starter-web to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: spring-boot-starter to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: scala-library to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: scalatest_2.11 to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: scalactic_2.11 to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: scala-reflect to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: scala-xml_2.11 to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: maven-reporting-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: doxia-sink-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: scalacheck_2.11 to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: test-interface to classpath
[DEBUG] joining on thread Thread[org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(),5,org.apache.avro.tool.Main]
[DEBUG] Setting accessibility to true in order to invoke main().
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

Comment: Could you please post the `mvn -X clean generate-sources` log?

Comment: I added the output minus some listing of jar files.